# Is there a way to add a new column to already created Firebase database in Swift?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I already have email and password as fields in a Firebase database, but I'd like each user to have 'points' as well. Is there a way to add this column to all users so 'points' can be called on 'users' and be recognized? Thanks.

This is where my saveUser function is

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseDatabase

class DBProvider {
    private static let _instance =  DBProvider();

    static var Instance: DBProvider {
        return _instance;
    }

    var dbRef: FIRDatabaseReference {
        return FIRDatabase.database().reference();
    }

    var driversRef: FIRDatabaseReference {
        return dbRef.child(Constants.DRIVERS)
    }


    func saveUser(withID: String,email: String, password: String) {
        let data: Dictionary<String, Any> = [Constants.EMAIL: email, Constants.PASSWORD: password];

        driversRef.child(withID).child(Constants.DATA).setValue(data);
    }




} //class
```

And this is where it's called.

```
func signUp(withEmail: String, password: String, loginHandler: LoginHandler?) {
    FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: withEmail, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in
        if error != nil {
            self.handleErrors(err: error as! NSError, loginHandler: loginHandler);
        } else {
            if user?.uid != nil {
                // store the user to database

                DBProvider.Instance.saveUser(withID: user!.uid, email: withEmail, password: password)
                //log in the user
                self.login(withEmail: withEmail, password: password, loginHandler: loginHandler)
            }
        }
    })

} //sign up func
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just add the `points` property to the user at any time.

Save it in the same manner that you are saving `email` and `password` now. As a side note: I would not save the password in clear, at least hash it and send the hash to Firebase.

Your **new** users will have points also, but your old ones will not, so need to update the entries for them by hand:
- retrieve them from Firebase
- add `points` to them.

Comment: I can save points to new users, but when i try to call "user.points" to display them (and I have been able to display "user.email"), I get an error "FIRuser has no member "points". I even deleted the accounts that had no points column in firebase (database and auth) because there were't that many. Is this because there are branches without 'points' making accounts?

Comment: if your code is in production and other people are using it, yes. they are adding users that don't conform to the new model.